# Chrome stop working after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, google-chrome, mesa, i915

Last night I've upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and now Chrome won't start.

```
10:20:00 /opt/google/chrome$ ./chrome
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to open i915 (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
failed to load driver: i915
MESA-LOADER: failed to open kms_swrast (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
failed to load driver: kms_swrast
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
failed to load swrast driver
```

Also other apps start randomly with screen defects.

```
kernel 5.4.0-39
Gigabyte H61N-USB3 16GB RAM
i3250 (intel HD graphics 2500)
no additional video cards
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue which look like is related to Intel Drivers. This command line solved the issue:

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Reboot and everything is back being normal.

Comment: completing [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255324/869785) , after you remove xserver-xorg-video-intel and restarting, the lightdm couldn't start so I installed the same package again sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel and restarted, no it's working fine