# Chromium not starting on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 `x86_64` and using `chromium` installed with `snap`:

```
$ snap list 
Name               Version          Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
chromium           84.0.4147.89     1229  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
core18             20200707         1880  latest/stable  canonical✓  base
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853  1506  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.45.2           8542  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
```

It all seems up-to-date, but `chromium` can not start. If I launch it, it aborts the execution. In both `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log`, the following line is generated:

```
kernel: [ 1590.847960] traps: chrome[5324] trap int3 ip:557cd4d7b152 sp:7fffde23a9c0 error:0 in chrome[557cd1a59000+7234000]
```

Also, in `/var/log/apport.log`, for each execution attempt, this line appears:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 5556) Thu Jul 16 10:32:47 2020: host pid 5324 crashed in a separate mount namespace, ignoring
```

What could it be the problem?

---

Note that the program is `chromium`, but despite this, the log lines automatically report the name `chrome`, for reasons I do not know (maybe because `chromium` is anyway based on `chrome`).

---

**Update**: when launched from a terminal, according to a suggestion in an answer, I get:

```
$ chromium-browser --disable-extensions
[11036:11036:0716/152514.953429:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
WARNING: Kernel has no file descriptor comparison support: Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

With `chromium --disable-extensions`, the message is the same.

---

**Update 2**:

```
$ chromium-browser --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to open i915 (search paths /snap/chromium/1229/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
failed to load driver: i915
MESA-LOADER: failed to open kms_swrast (search paths /snap/chromium/1229/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
failed to load driver: kms_swrast
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /snap/chromium/1229/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
failed to load swrast driver
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

and the same with `chromium --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer`. I did not intentionally install any graphic driver, so I guess I'm using the default ones shipped with Ubuntu 20.04. I use the CPU integrated graphic card, CPU is Intel Core i5 4670.

I also tried to run `chromium-browser --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer` after `export MESA_GLSL_CACHE_DISABLE=true`, but the error messages are the same as above.

Comment: it must have been something you had installed previously as I just installed chromium on 20.04 and it runs fine

Comment: @ScottStensland I can not recall if I made any updates (from `aptitude`) yesterday, when `chromium` still worked. Is there a way to find out what could it be the conflict?

Comment: I tend to steer away from using chromium ... I would uninstall chromium and instead install chrome using  https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/   which gives you a lightly newer release anyway ...  if you must use chromium I would uninstall its snap and install using the .deb from  say https://pkgs.org/download/chromium-browser

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks for your suggestions. Personally I am not familiar with `snap` and I understand your advices. However, if it's possibile, I would like to make any attempt to keep the current `chromium` installation and make it work as it currently is.

Comment: This can also happen by wrongly tweaking the system's OOM settings as suggested here https://serverfault.com/a/142003/105082

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the fundamental observations from the Antoine Pintout answer, I recalled that I had installed several new fonts, not included in the Ubuntu base system.

A first effect was that the "Save page" window in Chromium was no more able to use any font, displaying instead a vertical empty rectangle `▯` for each letter. It is exactly the same issue as in the Antoine Pintout [linked report](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/chromium-file-chooser-is-not-displaying-font/17021/4).

However, Chromium was still working. Then, after some days, it presented the issue of my question.

Yesterday and today, Ubuntu deployed several updates that I applied: between them, `snapd` and `xorg-*` (but not `xserver-xorg-video-intel`). After the updates, Chromium still didn't start.

Instead of using the workaround suggested by Antoine Pintout, **I simply removed the fonts I had installed**, and **the issue disappeared**: Chromium was able again to start. I don't know if the recent updates contributed to this.

It is worth noting that I then reinstalled all the fonts that I had just removed, and Chromium was not affected by them, this time: it works. Again, I don't know if the updates brought some fixes.

By the way, the integration between Chromium, `snap` and Ubuntu still requires some improvements.

Comment: I restarted after removing the fonts to get Chromium to work. I suspect rebuilding the font cache or doing something akin to that would also work.

Answer (score 19):

I just got this problem, seemingly out of the blue. Turns out I may be related to a problem I already reported about fonts not loading in the Chromium Snap.

I found the following workaround :

1. First, close all instances of chromium
2. Empty global and local font cache. Erase all existing cache files and rescan. Rerun Chromium:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
   rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
   sudo fc-cache -r -v
   rm -rf ~/snap/chromium/common/.cache/fontconfig/
   chromium-browser
   ```

This set of commands is a workaround for a problem I already reported here:
[[chromium] File chooser is not displaying font](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/chromium-file-chooser-is-not-displaying-font/17021/4)

Comment: Thank you so much! I installed some fonts in the system days ago. I had the exact same issue as in your [linked report](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/chromium-file-chooser-is-not-displaying-font/17021/4): no fonts in the "Save file" window. Actually I did not follow your workaround, but simply removed some of the fonts I had installed. Now `chromium` starts and the "Save file" window is ok. If you want, you can edit your answer mentioning, as an alternative, to remove the previously installed fonts, which worked for me. I really couldn't figure out they were the problem here.

Comment: No worries, I'm working with new fonts on a daily basis, narrowing which ones are causing trouble would be a very time consuming. Consider posting your own answer. 
Anyways, the problem lies in how Snap is handling fonts (I would disculp Chromium in this situation as Chrome is working flawlessly, and Chromium from other packet systems is not affected...) and not which fonts we are using...

Comment: An even more curious fact is that, after removing the new fonts I had installed, I tried to reinstall **all** of them, expecting to create again the issue. Instead, `chromium` still perfectly works. Yesterday and today, several updates have been deployed, including `snapd` and `xorg-*` (but not `xserver-xorg-video-intel`): maybe there's a relation.

Comment: This fix did not survive a reboot for the first issue I had, but in this case it did. Weird.

Comment: Ok! Yes, I also am persuaded that `snap` may be responsible for this (even if I do not know it in detail). Ubuntu should perfection this feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its helpful when troubleshooting a crash if you launch the application directly from a terminal so you can see the app's output messages,  instead of from the Ubuntu dash or launcher bar ... so open up a terminal (  ctrl + alt + t )   and in terminal issue

```
chromium  --disable-extensions
```

Does it run better now ?   if yes then issue is probably due to a bad extension ... if it still crashes can you update your question with a copy and paste of messages shown in the terminal

**UPDATE**  alright now from your new crash its GPU related, so launch from terminal using

```
chromium  --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
```

and lets see if it comes up OK or not  ...  btw did you install graphics drivers yourself ?  or are you using the default nouveau ?

**UPDATE2**  just googling about I see [Chrome stop working after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255304/chrome-stop-working-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04)   so if you are willing to destroy your Ubuntu install meaning anything of value is safely backed up ( Dropbox, or MEGA nz, or on a memory stick, cloud ...) run the suggested removal of package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` ... I am on a Ubuntu 20.04 laptop using the default nouveau drivers even though I have an Nvidia card yet I do have that intel package installed as per

```
dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

which comes back with

```
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git20200226-1            amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

OK so I just issued

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

and after a reboot can confirm the machine is fine so that may resolve your issue (as per above link) ... depending on your risk appetite try that purge and let us know (as long as your backups are current )

Comment: I just edited the question with the new information. I did not intentionally install graphics drivers, so I *guess* I'm using the default ones.

Comment: Thanks for your research. I Googled it several times, but I didn't find the solution you mentioned here. I am using Intel `i915` driver, as from `lshw -c video | grep driver`. I think that after purging `xserver-xorg-video-intel` there's chance that I will have no driver at all. The problem would not be the backup, but to make such a huge modification in a system which should be as stable and "unpolluted" as possible. So, I won't try this solution. But I really would like to thank you for all the effort and contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Those commands have fixed my broken packages. Chromium and other apps worked seamlessly afterward

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*
```

Comment: So what was the cause of the problem?

Comment: it worked for me using above. its kind of app firewall on system which let app have config to use. a profile may be at snap level which might be culprit. For me, chromium had not started after last  time system had drained battery. it didn't got chance to have graceful shutdown/closure.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't answer the question as such but may help someone... Tripped over this at work on my dell laptop after installing windows fonts and the workaround posited by Antoine regarding fonts solved the issue.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1864365/comments/33

However just tried the same fix on my Intel NUC and I get this

```
Gtk-Message: 10:31:24.401: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 10:31:24.402: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[10624:10624:0100/000000.486036:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I tried this

`$ sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module`

and a restart but still get the same error.

`$ lshw -c video | grep driver`

returns i915. So I'm guessing the driver might be the issue here as well as the fonts?

Confirmed that removing the windows fonts I installed solves the issue.

Anyway hope this helps someone.

M

Answer (score -1):

In my case , I tried all above mentioned, but nothing really helped...
When I tried with the

"**snap connect chromium:gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-28-1804:gnome-3-28-1804**"

I found the gnome-3-28-1804 is not installed so I installed first by

"**sudo snap install gnome-3-28-1804**"

and chromium stared wirking is my system